# Display message and lock workbook if error

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA code for running several operations. It unlocks Workbook before running and protects after operation is done. However sometimes code runs into an error due to user opening windows or doing something in background. I would like it not to display any kind of Visual Basic standard message like "Compile error" but my custom message whenever code runs to any kind of error and use `ThisWorkbook.Protect Password:="123456", Structure:=True, Windows:=False`.

P.S. Time break is due operation system on my computer can't handle the processes that fast.

```
Sub TryToDoEverything()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ThisWorkbook.Unprotect Password:="123456"

    ufProgress.LabelProgress.Width = 0
    ufProgress.Show

FractionComplete (0) 'Next step

Worksheets("MAIN").Activate

Call MakeMyFolder
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))
DoEvents
FractionComplete (0.1) 'Next step

If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("J2").Value = True Then
Call opentemplateWordOL
End If
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("J2").Value = False Then
End If

DoEvents
FractionComplete (0.2) 'Next step
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))

If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("J2").Value = True Then
Call opentemplateWordPL
End If
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("J2").Value = False Then
End If

DoEvents
FractionComplete (0.4) 'Next step
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))

FractionComplete (1) 'Next step

Worksheets("MAIN").Activate

Unload ufProgress

ThisWorkbook.Protect Password:="123456", Structure:=True, Windows:=False

    TaskComplete.Show
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience it is not good to use ThisWorkbook many times, in the beginning of your code use the following,

```
dim thisWb as excel.workbook
set thisWb = thisworkbook
```

then instead of ThisWorkbook use thisWb and it won't matter if the user clicks on another different wb during execution.

Comment: Thanks for useful tip. However I would like to add if error to my code.

Comment: This is unfounded and useless advice that adds an unnecessary level of indirection that obscures which workbook we're working with. `ThisWorkbook` is a project-wide identifier that holds a reference to the specific workbook that contains the VBA code that's running. This answer takes good, solid advice about `ActiveWorkbook` and turns it into bad advice about `ThisWorkbook`. `ActiveWorkbook` can change depending on what the code (or user) is doing during execution, that's why you keep a named reference to it. `ThisWorkbook` only ever refers to one very specific object. Copying it is useless.